Problem exporting localization screenshots in Xcode 15
Just installed Xcode 15 and trying to export localization screenshots with the basic Hello World example provided by Xcode.
However I see that the "Include screenshots" checkbox when I click Product > Export localizations is greyed out.
I have created a test plan and in the test plan I have set

Application Language => English
Application Region => United States
Automatic Screen Capture => On, and keep all
Preferred Capture Format => Screenshot
Localization Screenshots => On
Attachments => On, and keep all

My test code is something like below:
import XCTest

final class JumboUITestsLaunchTests: XCTestCase {

    override class var runsForEachTargetApplicationUIConfiguration: Bool {
        true
    }

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        continueAfterFailure = false
    }

    func testLaunch() throws {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launchArguments = ["-AppleLanguages", "(en)", "-AppleLocale", "en_US"] // Launch the app in English
        app.launch()

        // Insert steps here to perform after app launch but before taking a screenshot,
        // such as logging into a test account or navigating somewhere in the app
        let screenshot = app.screenshot()
        let attachment = XCTAttachment(screenshot: screenshot)
        attachment.name = "Localization Screenshot"
        attachment.lifetime = .keepAlways
        add(attachment)
    }
}

I can see the screenshot under Report Navigator when I click on "Gallery" for the particular test case. But it is not allowing me to include screenshots in "Export localizations"
What could be the issue?

Do you mean the checkmark is disabled? Did you run the tests, after setting the configurations and before selecting export?

@MojtabaHosseini yup the checkmark is disabled. I ran the tests after setting the configurations and before selecting the export.

Your configuration is correct and it should be enabled as you can see here. Maybe restarting your mac helps.

yup i tried this but it still doesn't enable the checkbox

Did you tried to delete cache? Run those commands in terminal                                 rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode

hmm still no luck... should i create new project as ios app or as multiplatform app?
